# Binomial distribution with parameters p and N, p is distributed to a beta distribution with parameters r and s

Tags: stochastic-processes

For each given $p$, let $X$ have a binomial distribution with parameters $p$ and $N$. Suppose $p$ is distributed according to a beta distribution with parameters r and s. Find the resulting distribution of $X$. When is this distribution uniform on $x=0,1,2,...N$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want (and much more), is given at [Beta-binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 1):

The key concept you need to use is the [law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). Let $P$ be the random variable that denotes the success probability of the Binomial distribution. We know the distribution of $P$. Suppose we also know that $P=p$ for some $0 < p < 1$. Given this information, you should be able to write down the probability of the event $\{X=k\}$. Mathematically speaking, we know how to write down $P(X=k \mid P=p)$.

If $P$ were a discrete distribution, the law of total probability will read as $$P(X=k) = \sum P(X=k \mid P = p) Pr(P = p)$$ where the sum is over all the values taken by the discrete random variable $P$. But in your example, $P$ is continuous which means this summation is replaced by integration.

The final step in finding $P(X=k)$ is to substitute the expressions for $P(X=k \mid P = p)$ and $Pr(P=p)$ into the integral and evaluate the integral. You might find [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) link useful for evaluating the integral. If you are still getting stuck, show us your work and the difficulties you are facing. I am sure someone will chip in with more hints.